# Why did (half-of) the bounty not go to me after the bounty period expired?

Tags: discussion

In this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24299/how-where-did-the-wizards-usually-carry-their-wands/56550#56550), a bounty was offered. There were already a few good answers one of which was accepted. But during the bounty period I posted an answer which the OP chose as accepted. Note: my answer is NOT the highest 'voted'.

According to [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/904/21267) answer, if the bounty period runs out and the bounty giver does not post the bounty, half of the rep points go to the highest scoring answer(s) OR an answer which was accepted during the bounty period (**unless** the bounty giver specifically chooses to give the bounty).

Now, I have no problem not receiving a bounty, or even any rep points, so my point isn't about that. **I would like to know how the system works**, did the system give the points to the highest 'voted' answer or if in this case the bounty giver **chose** to give the bounty to a certain answer (perfectly fine).

Comment: [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31370/976) answer had more votes than yours and got the bounty because of that, I think.

Comment: @DVK I see. So I guess I must be mistaken when I thought that the bounty (or part of it) goes to an answer accepted during the bounty period?

Comment: I've never heard anything about it going to an accepted answer, but I do see that in the MSE FAQ now.  Something else must be going on.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yeah, I just thought that was the case from this answer: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/903/what-happens-if-no-one-answers-a-bounty/904#904.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bounty was manually awarded. The offerer chose to give it to the other answer.

Comment: Cool. So could you clarify whether my assumption re the bounty going to the answer accepted during the bounty period is correct or not? Thanks!

Comment: @mooz - that is correct, *if* the bounty is *not* manually awarded

Comment: @SSumner Makes sense. Thanks for that!